# Is there a way to automate 'control userpasswords2'

Tags: windows, passwords, automation

The command 'control userpasswords2' displays a GUI that allows you to set it to where users are not required to enter a username and password to login.  If you uncheck it and hit apply, it prompts you for the password of the currently selected user.

I want to automate this.  Is there a way to make these changes from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

This is done using the [Sysinternals Autologon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autologon) utility.  From the command line, run:

> Autologon enables you to easily configure Windows’ built-in autologon mechanism. Instead of waiting for a user to enter their name and password, Windows uses the credentials you enter with Autologon, which are encrypted in the Registry, to log on the specified user automatically.

`autologon.exe /accepteula username domain password`

Answer (score 0):

You're asking about setting automatic logon via the command line.

This is specified under the registry key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`
by the values of `AutoAdminLogon`, `DefaultUserName` and `DefaultPassword`.

These registry updates can be done using the
[reg command](https://ss64.com/nt/reg.html) :

```
REG ADD "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v AutoAdminLogon /t REG_SZ /d 1 /f
REG ADD "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultDomainName /t REG_SZ /d DOMAIN-NAME /f
REG ADD "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultUserName /t REG_SZ /d USER-NAME /f
REG ADD "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultPassword /t REG_SZ /d PASSWORD /f
```

Comment: This exposes the password in plain text. I was looking for an approach that had Windows cache the password.

Comment: Any caching will have to be done inside the installation app/script. For a script, you may convert it to an `.exe` file.